# Tableau Prep: How can I refer to a parameter in the Custom SQL query?

Tags: tableau-api, tableau-desktop, tableau-prep

Using Tableau Prep Builder version 2021.4.4 I connected to Postgresql database (version 12) and created a Custom Query as the only input in the Flow.
Then I created a parameter (my_date).
In the custom query I have:
select my_field
from my_table
where date = -- How can I refer to my_date?

I have already tried the following but all failed:

```
where date = ${my_date}-- syntax error at or near "$" 
where date = $my_date  -- syntax error at or near "$"
where date = :my_date  -- syntax error at or near ":"
where date = (my_date) -- "my_date" does not exist
where date = my_date   -- "my_date" does not exist
where date = $1        -- Index 0 out of bounds for length 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use < > , for example:

```
where date = <my_date>
```

OR

```
where date = '<my_date>'
```